What types of work did enslaved people do in the Americas?
Obviously, they were used in agriculture, but I'm interested in an overview of something like the proportion of work that was done by enslaved people in different industries, especially with references. Most studies I can find on this look at one industry in one region rather than attempt to give an overall picture of the sort of tasks enslaved people were put to throughout the Americas. If most were used for agriculture (probably), how did that compare to how many were used for housework or for skilled labor? I'm mostly interested in North America during the 18th century up to the early 19th century.
For some examples of sources that I've found (and the quality of sources I'm interested in)...

Bezis-Selfa, J. (1997). Slavery and the disciplining of free labor in the colonial mid-Atlantic iron industry. Pennsylvania History: A Journal of Mid-Atlantic Studies, 64, 270-286.
Bailey, R. (1994). The other side of slavery: black labor, cotton, and textile industrialization in Great Britain and the United States. Agricultural History, 68(2), 35-50.
Outland, R. B. (1996). Slavery, work, and the geography of the North Carolina naval stores industry, 1835-1860. The Journal of Southern History, 62(1), 27-56.

This stuff is great of course, but I'm looking for a more general overview (though still in the form of a reputable study).

Comments have been moved to chat.  OP has edited the question to address most/all of the comments raised.  If you feel the question should be re-opened, please vote to do so. If you feel that additional edits are required prior to re-open, comment below.

I want to find the time to draft an answer to this, but I won't have time till at least New Year's Day. Won't be particularly comprehensive, but might be a start.
